# Wire library causing samd21 based board to stop working

Tags: i2c, wire-library, pcb-design

A bit of a general question, but asking in case someone has stumbled onto a similar problem before. A friend and I designed a custom PCB board based on the ATSAMD21G microprocessor. The board has a accelerometer connected on I2C and a NRF24 connected on SPI.

The rest of the functionality of the board is working as expected. My friend, who lives in a different country is able to use his copies of the board (all 5 copies were made by the same manufacturer in the same batch) without issue. But on my end, attempting to call the wire library causes loop to not execute. We wonder, if we are missing a potential software issue. We already checked that the core for the boards, the IDE and libraries are the same. And I have previously used the IDE for other wire.h based projects.

[image]

Comment: Does your board run your friend's .hex file ok?

Comment: Using J-flash (j-link programmer) I get a "cannot download file" error when I try to flash the .bin, .hex of the sketch he sent me. I will explore other options, but not sure how to flash atm. J-flash did work for flashing the bootloader.

Comment: why you don't upload over USB bootloader if you flashed it?

Comment: I wasn't aware this could be done in the IDE. Done some googling. So I should try to upload it via the command prompt, instead of j-link?

Comment: maybe try "Upload with programmer" from the Sketch menu

Comment: It turns out the microprocessor somehow got  locked when I was trying to upload the bootloader, and unable to get it fixed. I will have to let it go for now since I tried everything I could find online and couldn't unlock and erase it,